# SQL Server returns question mark for some unicode chars

Tags: sql-server, unicode, sql-server-2016

In a `nvarchar(512)` field if i store unicode chars like this:

```
UPDATE MYTABLE SET UNICODEFIELD = 'TﾚEﾎSￔTﾙ'
```

when i query it i get

`T?E?S?T?`

It looks like the "unusual" chars are not considered as unicode, i would expect the "?" behavior in case of `varchar`, while with `nvarchar` it should work fine, i am expecting

`TﾚEﾎSￔTﾙ`

as output, instead of

`T?E?S?T?`

Does anyone have an idea about this?

Comment: this qusetion is marked as duplcite, but it is not a duplicate, the other qusetion is about the N prefix, the answer here is about it. I think it is better to leave it as a separate question because it could be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using a `varchar`, not an `nvarchar`. `'TﾚEﾎSￔTﾙ'` = `'T?E?S?T?'` as characters like `ﾚ` can't be stored in a `varchar`.

Use a literal `nvarchar`:

```
UPDATE MYTABLE SET UNICODEFIELD = N'TﾚEﾎSￔTﾙ';
```

Comment: Yes. simple as that. Up to now i always ignored that "N" since i used to store unicode data through copmonents that were handling that for me. Thanks.